# Use a Query from the Destination db to limit OLE DB Source task in SSIS 2008

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, ssis

All,
I have a package that I'm building as a data importer so I can copy sets of data from my production environment and develop on another instance.

I have two tables that contain header and detail rows for service tickets.  Those service tickets are tied back to orders.

I am pulling the service tickets from a certain time window, however, the originating orders fall outside of the date range that I'm pulling for the tickets.

I want to be able to take the following steps in an SSIS package:

1. Import the header and detail rows within the given date range from prod to dev
2. Select the relevant order numbers from dev tables
3. Use the list of order numbers to import only the relevant orders from prod

I poked through other answers and couldn't find answers that addressed this directly, so I apologize if there is an answer out there and I missed it.  I may not have been asking the question correctly.  I'm assuming that I would need to pull those order numbers into a temp table or variable in order to apply them as a filter.

As I write this, it just crossed my mind to use a join on the source system with the ticket to order tables and still use the date range to limit, but I'm still posting the question to see if anyone has dealt with this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your steps are already fairly clear, are you asking how to actually implement them? It looks like you can do all three steps by using SELECT statements in your data sources:

1. Build a SELECT statement dynamically with the correct dates to use in your data source. The dates could be programmatically generated in a script task, or saved in a database table and populated into variables. Then you copy the data across to the dev system.
2. Run a SELECT statement in the dev system that returns the order numbers, and copy the results to a table in the prod database.
3. Run a SELECT statement in the prod database that joins on the table from step 2 and copy the results back to dev.

An alternative to the table in steps 2 and 3 would be a lookup transformation, but if you have a large number of rows then using a table will probably be faster.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for some advice on actually implementing, and thanks for the response.  After thinking about it last night, I came to a similar conclusion where I'm going to try and use a global temp table in the prod system to bring the order numbers back over to, since I won't be able to create a permanent table.  Either way, I think you firmed up the idea.  I'll update once I give it a try today.